# Cannot invoke 'canEvaluatePolicy' with an argument list of type '(LAPolicy)' Swift2.0 Xcode 7

Tags: ios, swift, ios8

I have a problem with canEvaluatePolicy function.

I have declared this function like this :

```
func canEvaluatePolicy(policy: LAPolicy) {
    do {
        try authenticationObject.canEvaluatePolicy(.DeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Error: \(error.domain)")
    }
}
```

But when I want to use it like this:

```
if authenticationObject.canEvaluatePolicy(LAPolicy.DeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics) {
```

I have an error:

```
Error: Cannot invoke 'canEvaluatePolicy' with an argument list of type '(LAPolicy)'
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, assuming that `authenticationObject` is an [`LAContext`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/LocalAuthentication/Reference/LAContext_Class/index.html), you *can't* call its [`canEvaluatePolicy`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/LocalAuthentication/Reference/LAContext_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/LAContext/canEvaluatePolicy:error:) method without handling the error that it potentially throws. Making sure that errors get handled* is what `throws` methods are all about.

Second, when ObjC APIs that return `BOOL` with an `NSError` out-parameter are imported into Swift, they lose the Boolean return type—they become throwing functions with no return type (well, `Void` as the return type... same thing). That's because, for these functions, it's assumed that a `false` return always comes with an error and a `true` return is always indicative of no error.

So you don't need to test the (lack of) return value—instead, you want something like this:

```
do {
    try authenticationObject.canEvaluatePolicy(.DeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics)
    // if you get here, "can evaluate" is true
    // feel free to call evaluatePolicy or whatever
} catch {
    print(error) // or present an alert, etc.
}
```

Or, to wrap it in your own local function:

```
func canEvaluate() -> Bool {
    do {
        try authenticationObject.canEvaluatePolicy(.DeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics)
        return true
    } catch {
        print(error) // or present an alert, etc.
        return false
    }
}
```

In real-world usage, you probably want some pattern matching on your `catch` clauses—some of the [`LAError`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/LocalAuthentication/Reference/LAContext_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/LAError) values are things you probably want to swallow (if the user presses Cancel, there's no need to show another alert saying they pressed Cancel), and others are things you'd want to interact for.

<sup>* Of course, "handling" an error can be as simple as choosing to ignore it, or choosing to abort—though some of those choices may be detrimental to your user experience. But it's your choice that's the important part here... just like Swift 1 introduced the idea of having to consider optionality as a way of making sure the code you write is safe, Swift 2 introduces the idea of having to consider possible errors.</sup>